# Did Portal on Xbox 360 receive the updated ending?

Tags: xbox-360, portal

[Kotaku reported Valve updated the PC version of Portal](http://kotaku.com/5485075/valve-updates-portal-again-now-with-new-ending) with an updated ending.

**Did this change ever make it to the XBox 360 version?**

Was the final scene shown or referenced in Portal 2, either

- as a video or
- with signs or references to the:

  > party escort submission position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the orange boxes for consoles were never updated after release. The changes made to the PC version were

> After killing GlaDOS Chell wakes up in the aperture parking lot. A robotic voice is heard saying "Thank you for assuming the party escort position" and Chell is dragged away (presumably by the robot) while the screen fades to black

These changes were not present in console versions of the game.

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1940927

Comment: Do you have a source for this? [Xbox 360 Magazine said otherwise](http://www.oxm.co.uk/17861/portal-gets-brand-new-ending-video-inside/).

Comment: That article only says there is an updated ending. It doesn't specify what platforms it was on. I have a link to the steam forums from 2011 which says only the PC was updated but I don't know if form discussions can be taken as sources on here. http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1940927

Comment: Thanks and accepted; that was the Xbox 360 article that prompted my question.